# "Add custom HTML" block in WordPress previews my code perfectly, but when I come back, it's all messed up

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add a custom HTML block to a page in WordPress. I paste in my code, check the preview and I see that it's working perfectly. But then I update it, and when I get back to the page, I get a bunch of gibberish and my code is edited.

Here's what it looks like in the preview:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyBMz.png

And it remains functional even when I click "Update":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA4pH.png

But when I try to visit the page again, it's all messed up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeMIe.png

I noticed that WordPress removes all the script tags and all the tags that call a function when I visit the page again.

Does WordPress not allow script tags on HTML blocks, or do I have to do something with my code?

I read that I can use Code Snippets or Code Embed plugins to add Javascript codes. But I don't want to upgrade to business plan as I am just testing. Is there any way to make this work without paying?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the shortcode for that, by the shortcode you will put any HTML or JS or PHP code in that, [see reference](https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/)